# Updating detailDescriptionLabel data from UITableView selected index

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have a split view controller for iPad with a drill-down table on the left.  I am able to populate the tables with a drill-down without issue but I cannot seem to get the item I clicked within the UITableView on the left side to show up in detailDescriptionLabel on the right side.

I have the following code in my ProductViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

NSLog(@"Row clicked: %i", indexPath.row);

if (_delegate != nil) {
    Product *product = (Product *) [_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [_delegate productSelectionChanged:product];
}

DetailedVC *detailView = [[DetailedVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
NSLog(@"User clicked on: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]);
detailView.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
}
```

What happens here is I push the DetailedVC into the left side where my table view is and what I really want to do is see the row clicked updated in my detailed view on the right.  I am able to see in the Log window that I clicked on a certain index so I know I am capturing the click event and getting a value.

Inside my DetailedVC.m I have the following code to update this label.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self configureView];
}

- (void) configureView {

if (self.detailItem) {

    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];

    NSLog(@"Item: %@", [self.detailItem description]);
}
}
```

If I edit the viewDidLoad I get a (null) for the [self.detailItem description]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"Detail description label: %@", [self.detailItem description]);
}
```

ProductViewController.h

```
@interface ProductViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *_products;
UITableView *_productsTableView;
id<ProductSelectionDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *productsTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *products;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ProductSelectionDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
@class ProductViewController;
@class DetailedVC;

@interface TabAndSplitAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
ProductViewController *_productViewController;
DetailedVC *_detailedViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ProductViewController *productViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailedVC *detailedViewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

NSMutableArray *products = [NSMutableArray array];
[products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithName:@"Product 1 Name" desc:@"Product 1 Description"]];
_detailedViewController.product = [products objectAtIndex:0];

// Override point for customization after app launch.
//create split view controller
RootVC *rvc=[[RootVC alloc] init];
rvc.title=@"Root VC";
DetailedVC *dvc=[[DetailedVC alloc] init];
dvc.title=@"Detailed VC";
_productViewController.delegate = _detailedViewController;

MySplitViewController *msc = [[MySplitViewController alloc] initwithLeftVC:rvc rightVC:dvc];
msc.title=@"First";
//create a temporary VC to show in second tab
SecondViewController *vc2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
vc2.title=@"Second";

//make an array containing these two view controllers
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:msc,vc2,nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
tabBarController.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

for(UITabBarItem*t in tabBarController.tabBar.items)
{
    t.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
    t.badgeValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",([tabBarController.tabBar.items indexOfObject:t]+1)];
}

//the views are retained their new owners, so we can release
[rvc release];
[dvc release];
[msc release];
[vc2 release];

// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

MySplitViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MySplitViewController : UIViewController
{
UINavigationController *leftController;
UINavigationController *rightController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *leftController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *rightController;

- (void)layoutViews:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation initialVerticalOffset:(float)offset;

- (MySplitViewController*) initwithLeftVC:(UIViewController*)leftvc rightVC:(UIViewController*)rightvc;
@end
```

MySplitViewController.m

```
- (MySplitViewController*) initwithLeftVC:(UIViewController*)leftvc rightVC:(UIViewController*)rightvc
{
if(self=[super init])
{
    UINavigationController *lnc=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftvc];
    lnc.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    self.leftController=lnc;
    [lnc release];

    UINavigationController *rnc=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rightvc];
    rnc.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    self.rightController=rnc;
    [rnc release];
}
return self;
}
```

Product.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Product : NSObject {

NSString *_productID;
NSString *_productDescription;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *productID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *productDescription;

- (Product *)initWithName:(NSString *)productID desc:(NSString *)productDescription;

@end
```

Product.m

```
#import "Product.h"

@implementation Product

@synthesize productID = _productID;
@synthesize productDescription = _productDescription;

- (Product *)initWithName:(NSString *)productID desc:(NSString *)productDescription {

if ((self = [super init])) {

    self.productID = productID;
    self.productDescription = productDescription;
}

return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you get the NSLog output from `configureView`? I can't see you setting `detailItem` anywhere.

Comment: No Jorn, the self.detailItem is not populated with a value in the DetailedVC.m so the NSLog inside the if... is never executed.  I was under the impression that this value was being set in the didSelectRowAtIndex method in the ProductViewController.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, please try this in ProductViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

  NSLog(@"Row clicked: %i", indexPath.row);

  Product *product = (Product *) [_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSLog(@"Product: %@", product);

  TabAndSplitAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSLog(@"appDelegate: %@", appDelegate);
  UITabBarController *tbc = appDelegate.tabBarController;
  NSLog(@"tbc: %@", tbc);
  MySplitViewController *msvc = tbc.selectedViewController;
  NSLog(@"msvc: %@", msvc);
  UINavigationController *rnc = msvc.rightController;
  NSLog(@"rnc: %@", rnc);
  DetailedVC *dvc = rnc.topViewController;
  NSLog(@"dvc: %@", dvc);

  dvc.detailDescriptionLabel.text = @"We found our DetailedVC";

  [dvc productSelectionChanged:product];
}
```

This code is not an example of how you should structure your program properly. This was just to help me (and you) understand your view controller hierarchy.

The initial idea of notifying a delegate when a product is selected is spot on, it just didn't work in your case because the objects weren't wired up properly. You should try to do that though. In the code you posted, I don't see a location where both the `ProductViewController`and the `DetailedVC` are both directly visible so that you could just say

```
productViewControllerInstance.delegate = detailedVCinstance;
```

The nearest to that is in AppDelegate where you have the `RootVC` instance `rvc`that presumably eventually will create the `ProductViewController` and the `dvc`. Maybe you could give the `dvc`to the `rvc`so that it can set it as the `ProductViewController`'s delegate when it's created. Good luck!

Comment: Ok Jorn, I now see the [self.detailItem description] showing a value for the row I clicked inside my configureView method with this: NSLog(@"Item: %@", [self.detailItem description]);  This was a great help BUT I am still not seeing the actual label in that view show any value.  I have a UILabel called detailDescriptionLabel as a property in my DetailedVC.h file and I have that wired up to the actual UILabel in the interface builder file DetailedVC.xib - this label has a placeholder value called 'Label' in the UI.  Run the app don't see the placeholder value, 'Label' or the updated value.

Comment: hm, maybe there is a problem hooking up your `detailDescriptionLabel ` outlet.
What do you get when you add `NSLog(@"Label: %@", self.detailDescriptionLabel);`to `configureView`?

Comment: I get this....  Label: <UILabel: 0x6cc0da0; frame = (34 118; 251 21); text = 'Baby Spinach  - 6x1lb'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6ca7910>>

Comment: oh - sorry, I was obviously trying to solve the wrong problem... I thought you weren't seeing the description in the detail view controller that you pushed on the nav controller; but you don't see it in the right hand side detail view of a split view controller...
ok, so which class is your `ProductViewController`'s _delegate an instance of and how does its `productSelectionChanged:` method look? is it getting called?

Comment: Ok, I added my ProductViewController.h file to the thread above.  I am using ProductViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>   My productSelectionChanged method is in the DetailedVC.m file and is not getting called.

Comment: I see... is your `DetailedVC` instance that's on the right hand side of the split view wired up to any other object? The AppDelegate? The `ProductViewController` instance? You have to get ahold of a reference to that object. Could you also please show what your 'productSelectionChanged:' method in 'DetailedVC' looks like?

Comment: Ah, now I think I've understood what you're trying to do... do you want to use the `DetailedVC` on the right as the delegate of your `ProductViewController`? Is that right? You say your `productSelectionChanged:` does not get called. That would mean that the `_delegate` is `nil`. Have you made a connection in the XIB file?

Comment: I loaded the AppDelegate.m above.  Yes, when I click on an item in my tableView (ProductViewController)I want to see that item in my DetailedVC.  The delegate IS nil and I tried to hook up the ProductViewController and DetailedVC in the AppDelegate.h file but Interface Builder will not connect to either xib when I drag and try to connect, for example, @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailedVC *detailedViewController; to the DetailVC.xib view.

Comment: ok, so things aren't wired up correctly... there are many ways to do it and so there are many many ways for it to go wrong... ;-)
can you show me your `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`? How many XIB-Files do you have? What are they called?

Comment: I added it above Jorn.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: ok, I don't see that a `ProductViewController` is brought up on the screen in there anywhere. Is it contained in the `RootVC` in the `MySplitViewController`? Ist `dvt`the `DetailedVC` that we are talking about? Or are there others?

Comment: Is is a mess?  What I have is a split view with a tab view.

Comment: Ok, the app has two table views on the right.  The first thing to appear is the UISplitView with RootVC, which has Categories, on the left and DetailVC on the right.  After the user selects from the table view in the RootVC then the ProductViewController displays all of the products available in that category.  Once the user selects a product I want to display the details about that product on the right in the DetailVC.  Make sense?  I don't have a variable called dvt, I do have one called dvc for the DetailVC.

Comment: Ok Jorn, I changed my didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my ProductViewController.m file just like you have it.  I got the row clicked as an integer value, I got a product with a description but the DetailedVC is (null).  Ideas?

Comment: ok, try it with more debug output as above. Does `MySplitViewController` inherit from UISplitViewController? Can you also please post your `initwithLeftVC:rightVC:`method?

Comment: MySplitViewcontroller does NOT inherit from UISplitViewController but instead just UIViewController.  I have posted the initWithLeftVC aboce as well.  There is no initWithRightVC.

Comment: I'm not sure why the productSelectionChanged isn't being called.  That would solve this.

Comment: Well, the delegate of the `ProductViewController` is not set. You are setting the delegate of **a** `ProductViewController`, but not of **the** one that is displayed. Please try another revision above - it will help me to understand your view controller hierarchy.

Comment: Ok Jorn, the productSelectionChanged got called this time!  The NSLog output is this:  Row clicked: 4
Product: Spring Mix Clamshell - 2lb
appDelegate: <TabAndSplitAppAppDelegate: 0x6cb5d90>
tbc: <UITabBarController: 0x6cb5e60>
msvc: <MySplitViewController: 0x6e30cd0>
rnc: <UINavigationController: 0x6e38f10>
dvc: <DetailedVC: 0x6e30db0>

Comment: Even though the productSelectChanged is being called in the DetailedVC.m file I am still seeing that NSLog(@"Description: %@", [self.detailItem description]); is still (null).  I am able to see a value in the DetailVC when I hardcode a value in the refresh method like so... self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = @"Some value..."; Hmmmm....

Comment: Well, how does your productSelectChanged: method look?

Comment: Ok Jorn, I think the problem is solved.  My productSelectionChanged method takes a Product called currentSelection.  I assign that local variable to self.product and then call [self refresh]; in the refresh method I assign the self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = (NSString *)self.product;  It only worked when I changed the assignment to the detailDescriptionLabel when I changed it from [self.detailItem description] to self.product AND even though my product is a class with an ID and description those attributes didn't have anything assigned to them.  I want to pass an object with attributes.

Comment: I added my Product header and implementation files above for your reference.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you now. The `detailItem` is nil because you aren't assigning anything to it. You are assigning to `product`. It's not easy to diagnose without the rest of the code, but my impression is that you have some debris in your code that's left over from the original project template and that's unused now; maybe that's confusing you a little. For example, I don't think you are using `_productViewController`and `_detailedViewController` in your `AppDelegate`, or `detailItem`in your `DetailedVC`, anymore.

Comment: Jorn, would you mind looking at this issue?  Maybe you can give me an answer on this one and I can give you more points.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007408/assign-returned-data-to-strongly-typed-object